# How to listen to text modify event of group widget (Java SWT)?

Tags: java, events, swt, listener

What I want to do is: When I change the title of Group widget (by calling `setText()` method), I need to check the title, if contains certain characters, I'll do something.

Now the problem is, how to listen to the text modify event of Group widget?

I tried `addListener(SWT.Modify, listener);` method, (see the example below), it's not working.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        shell.setText("Stackoverflow");

        final Group group = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        group.setText("title0");

        group.addListener(SWT.Modify, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Group title changed");
            }

        });

        Button btn = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btn.setText("Press to set title of Group."); 

        btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                group.setText("title1"); 
            }

        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Group` does not generate any events when `setText` is called.

Comment: You should do the check before calling `setText(String)`. You can even create a helper function that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have workaround here use `setData()` method on `Widget` class and add `PaintListener` to Group Widget

```java
group.setData(new String(group.getText()));

    group.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            if (e.widget instanceof Group) {
                Group grp = (Group)e.widget;
                String data = (String)grp.getData();
                if (!data.equals(grp.getText())) {
                    System.out.println("Title changed");
                    grp.setData(grp.getText()); //Keep new changed title as data
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Whenever title changes paint event will trigger. I have kept group widget title text as data and comparing the changes in paint listener.

Note that paint listener will be called many times, so suggest you keep very less code inside this.

Comment: That's exactly what I looking for!! Thanks a lot! I will pay attention to the fact that "paint listener will be called many times", thanks again!!

Comment: Welcome. Also edit the post and add import statements and Test class. Then it becomes easy for others to just copy and paste quickly your code into their editors and fix it.